# Superset customization. extend/modify

Tags: flask, apache-superset

I am trying to extend/modify Superset. My goal is to add a modified version of the "Edit Table" form with additional properties in the "List Column" tab. Currently there is [Column, Verbose Name, Type, Groupable, Filterable, Is temporal]. I would like to add a couple more such as "Is target", "Is predictor" etc.

[image: Superset Edit Table]

I am not sure the best way to do this.

I thought that trying to do it with Flask Blueprints would be the way to go but the documentation has only a very basic "hello world" type example:

```
from flask import Blueprint
simple_page = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates',
                        url_prefix='/simple_page')
@simple_page.route('/', defaults={'page': 'index'})
@simple_page.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    return "Ok"
```

How could I set up a blueprint to inherit pretty much everything in Superset but add a modified version of that form along with the necessary modifications to save the new columns to the database?

I am trying to avoid forking and creating my own modified version of Superset because that would be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you need, but I think my answer could save someone time and draw some conclusions because there are almost no examples on the net. What do my example: *1)* add custom drop-down into main menu *2)* change column edit fields.

I found [hook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.29/superset/__init__.py#L206) which provide possibility to do something when app run.
Also I found that in your case works [TableModelView](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.29/superset/connectors/sqla/views.py#L171). But `columns tab` works using [TableColumnInlineView](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.29/superset/connectors/sqla/views.py#L22). Structure of project:

```
├── superset_config.py
├── templates
│   ├── example.html
```

**superset_config.py** works automatically when run app:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, g, redirect
from flask_appbuilder import has_access


def flask_app_mutator(app):
    # my version of superset v0.29
    # be careful with imports! they are should be inside functions!
    # in other case config will not work
    from superset import appbuilder
    from superset.connectors.sqla.views import TableModelView, TableColumnInlineView
    # found our view and change something...
    for v in appbuilder.baseviews:
        if isinstance(v, TableModelView):
            table_columns = v.related_views[0]  # type: TableColumnInlineView
            table_columns.edit_columns = ['column_name', 'type']
    # add a new menu item
    appbuilder.add_link(
        'example',
        label='example',
        href='/example',
        category_icon='fa-file-text-o',
        category='Example')

# register our mutator - he will be called when app run
FLASK_APP_MUTATOR = flask_app_mutator

# just a new blue print for processing new menu item
example_bp = Blueprint(
    'example',
    __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_url_path='/static/report')


@example_bp.route('/example')
def example():
    # as I wrote above - be careful with imports...
    from superset import appbuilder
    if not g.user or not g.user.get_id():
        return redirect(appbuilder.get_url_for_login)

    return render_template('example.html', appbuilder=appbuilder)


BLUEPRINTS = [example_bp]
```

Run our app from directory where stored **superset_config.py**, login, open some table for edit (example: `http://0.0.0.0:8088/tablemodelview/edit/1`). You will see that fields of our view was changed + new menu item:

[image: edit columns]

You will see the basic layout of the `superset` if you open our menu item(or `http://0.0.0.0:8088/example`):
[image: custom page]

**example.html**:

```
{% extends 'superset/basic.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div>Hello world</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block tail_js %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='appbuilder/js/jquery-latest.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='appbuilder/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

But I'm sure that customization is time consuming. Some components works using [builded js packages](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.29/superset/assets/js_build.sh#L10). I can't guarantee that `UI` will work fine after `backend` mods.